# How do I change indent in php-mode to 2 spaces in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, indentation, php-mode

I try to change indent from 4 spaces to 2 spaces (I need to write code with this style).

I try to evaluate this in the buffer with php code:

```
(setq tab-width 2)
```

or

```
(setq-default tab-width 2)
```

but it didn't work, when I type TAB I got 4 spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok found it:

```
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

Comment: @CMCDragonkai maybe you're ussing different mode, I don't remember but I think this is for build in javascript-mode.

Comment: The mode looks like `PHP/l`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Ah, didn't notice that this is for php not javascript, the mode was build in (in GNU emacs) php mode.