# How to set 2 spaces indent in javascript-mode in Emacs?

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation

This is similar question as this [How do I change indent in php-mode to 2 spaces in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975997/how-to-change-indent-in-php-mode-to-2-spaces-in-emacs/18976040) but for javascript-mode, I've try the same

```
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

but it don't work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found this as well

```
(setq js-indent-level 2)
```

Comment: such a bummer that there are different variables to control this for every mode...

Comment: Unless your workplace uses different indentation in different languages — then it becomes a feature rather than a bug :)

Comment: They could follow the same naming conventions though.

Comment: They could default to using `tab-width` (or `c-basic-offset`) unless explicitly overridden.